# Bad Practice? Storing aggregate function data vs. querying

Tags: sql

We have a navbar menu that will need to contain the quantity of certain items following the section name. Additionally, each user of the system has a different quantity value. The closest analogy I can make to this is a user's inbox and mail folders with the count parenthesized near the name of the folder.

```
inbox (113)
sent (45)
MyFolder (161)
etc....
```

My question is this - The navbar is displayed on every page. I am inclined to store the count value of each folder for a user in a separate table, but know that this is considered a bad practice (ie. table normalization). The cost of making the query right now is small but the database will grow. Is querying the DB each time a view is requested (with aggregates) the best practice?

Comment: Could you cache the data in the app? Thats basically what you would be doing by storing it in the db.

Comment: "The cost of making the query right now is small but the database will grow." Sounds like premature optimization to me.

Comment: It is a small query... If the information is needed, that is the whole point of the database.  If you are worried about millions of users, then all of the other queries involved in the operation will need to be dealt with. Just go with the design, and optimize later.

Comment: My first thought is becareful of optimizing before you know if you have a slowdown.  However, that said, I dont think this is a bad practice.  As long as you have good triggers that will refresh your data this is an excellent way to affect a speed up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The cost of making the query right now is small but the database will grow.

Growing the database does not necessarily means that the time that it takes to get you the counts would grow proportionally. A good index structure would help your queries remain fast, even when the size of the database grows considerably. For example, if your query retrieves the count of child entities, and the child table has an index on the foreign key, then retrieving the count goes as fast as if you have stored the count in a separate table.

> Is querying the DB each time a view is requested (with aggregates) the best practice?

There is no universal answer. There are situations when you have to denormalize your data in order to achieve acceptable performance. This happens when your aggregate query is inherently complex, so trying to optimize it by adding an index or two does not work.

It does not look like your application is at the point where you have to denormalize, so I would keep the normalized structure in place. You can always add a table with aggregates if the performance becomes unacceptable later.